# Fallen palm fronds

Tags: trees

what can I use to cut up fallen palm fronds with please.  They average 2-3 metres in length.  I have not tried anything before.  Am seeking advice, thanks.

Comment: A pair of secateurs will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Palm fronds are best dealt with using a wood chipper. You won't need a heavy duty machine since the fronds are not woody like hard wood, but they will be dusty and create an uncomfortable breathing environment so a respirator of some kind will protect your lungs, plus ear protection and a hat to stop dust and chips from tangling your hair. Call a local tree person and see if they have a rate for chipping services. It will save you a lot of effort and inconvenience.

Failing that, consider long handle bypass pruners. The leaflets will be dry and easy but the main rib can be stringy and will test your wrist. You can then use the frond pieces as mulch.